# Vulkan diffuse shading doesn't change with object transformation

Tags: graphics, glsl, vulkan, shading, directional-light

System:
GPU: Intel(R) UHD Graphics

Here is my shader code:

vertex shader:

```
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 3) in vec2 uv;

layout(location = 0) out vec3 fragCol;

layout(push_constant) uniform Push {
 mat4 transform; // projection * view * model
 mat4 modelMatrix;
} push;

vec3 DIRECTION_TO_LIGHT = normalize(vec3(1.0, -10.0, -1.0));

void main() {
gl_Position = push.transform * vec4(position, 1.0);

vec3 normalWorldSpace = normalize(mat3(push.modelMatrix) * normal);

float lightIntensity = max(dot(normalWorldSpace, DIRECTION_TO_LIGHT), 0);

fragCol = lightIntensity * vec3(1.0);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 fragCol;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

layout(push_constant) uniform Push{
mat4 transform;
mat4 modelMatrix;
}push;

void main(){
outColor = vec4(fragCol, 1.0);
}
```

[image]

The dark parts of the model remain dark even while rotating on the z-axis. It is like the color is baked into the model which isn't the case.

I tried calculating the color on the fragment shader but that didn't work either.

Code calculating the transform matrix:

```
auto projectionMatrix = camera.getProjection() * camera.getView();

        for (auto& obj : gameObjects) {
//rotating doesn't change the dark pixels.
            obj.transform.rotation.y += glm::radians(45.0f) * deltaTime;
            SimplePushConstantData push{};
            auto modelMatrix = obj.transform.mat4();
            push.transform = projectionMatrix * modelMatrix;
            push.modelMatrix = modelMatrix;
            vkCmdPushConstants(commandBuffer, pipelineLayout,
                VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT | VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT,
                0, sizeof(SimplePushConstantData), &push);
            obj.model->bind(commandBuffer);
            obj.model->draw(commandBuffer);
        }
```

Comment: "*even while rotating on the z-axis*" Are you rotating the mesh itself or the *view* of the mesh? Which matrix are you manipulating, and are you sure you're manipulating the right one?

Comment: I mean rotating the model. I have tried rotating it in every way but the dark sides remain dark no matter what

Comment: My point is this: you have exactly one object in the scene. So there's no *visual* indicator that you're not rotating the *viewpoint* by accident. This could be something as simple as you putting the model matrix first in your C code while your GLSL clearly says that it comes second. And even if that's not the case, we have no evidence that you're generating your model matrix correctly. In short, there are plenty of places where bugs can occur, and you've only shown one of them.

Comment: What I mean is that even when I know the direction of the lighting, rotating the mesh 90 degrees on the z axis still doesn't change the lighting and it remains as if no rotation was made. Also, even on the lit side of the model there is no change in brightness with the topology which I thought was weird.

Comment: I know what you mean; I'm saying that there are lots of ways that could happen, and you have only shown us the code for *maybe* one of them. That is, if everything you claim about your program is true, then the thing you describe shouldn't be happening. Therefore, what you claim about your code cannot be true, but we cannot know *which* things are wrong. Not without seeing more code.

Comment: I have edited the post to show my matrix calculations